# Add/map attribute route based on condition in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, attributes

I need someone to point me in the right direction regarding attribute routing.
The problem I have is that I want to extend the default Route attribute so that I can check if a route should be mapped or not mapped (during *routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()*) based on various conditions. I have created a class that inherits from Attribute and implements IDirectRouteFactory and IRouteInfoProvider but I really do not know how to make MapMvcAttributeRoutes()  ignore my custom attribute. My first idea was to return a null RouteEntry but that does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomRouteAttribute : Attribute, IDirectRouteFactory, IRouteInfoProvider
{
    string _Template;

    public CustomRouteAttribute(string template, string controllerName)
    {
        if (ControllerUtil.IsControllerActive(controllerName))
        {
            //I do want this route to be mapped
            _Template = template;
        }
        else
        {
            //I do not want this route to be mapped
        }
    }

    public RouteEntry CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext context)
    {
        IDirectRouteBuilder builder = context.CreateBuilder(Template);
        builder.Name = Name;

        return builder.Build();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Template
    {
        get 
        {
            return _Template;
        }
    }
}
```